# script conversion from Perl to shell

Tags: perl, bash, shell

following is the code in perl.
Can we write the same thing in shell scripts ??
If yes how ?
I have used associative arrays but unable to achieve what this is doing

```
open MYFILE, "<", "$ARGV[0]" or die "Can't open $ARGV[0] file \n";

############ to retieve the info and put them in associative arrray ##############

$line = <MYFILE>;
@line1 = split(/,/ , $line);
$length = @line1;
$count = 0;
while($count < $length)
{
    $line1[$count] =~ s/^\"//; 
    $line1[$count] =~ s/\"$//;
    $count++;
}


$line = <MYFILE>;
@line2 = split(/,/ , $line);
$length = @line2;
$count = 0;
while($count < $length)
{
    $line2[$count] =~ s/^\"//; 
    $line2[$count] =~ s/\"$//;
    $count++;
}

$count = 0;
while($count < $length)
{
    $array{$line1[$count]}=$line2[$count];
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: I'm certain the above can be rewritten in bash. Have you tried anything? If so what went wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to convert from Perl to shell.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can translate that to a shell script: Just wrap the perl script in a here-doc, pass it to `perl`, and put `#!/bin/sh` at the top…

```
#!/bin/sh
perl - <<'END' $1
...
END
```

But more seriously, you might achieve enlightenment by rewriting the code in a different fashion. What you are doing is reading a line, splitting it at commata, and removing quotation marks at the beginning and end of each field:

```
sub get_fields {
  map { s/^"//; s/"$//; $_ } split /,/, $_[0];
}

my @keys = get_fields scalar <>; # 1st line
my @vals = get_fields scalar <>; # 2nd line

my %hash;
@hash{ @line1 } = @line2;
```

Except for the slice operation at the end, you can now more easily rewrite the code because it uses data flow instead of structured programming as the predominant paradigm. Not to mention that my code is shorter by an order of magnitude <sub>(in base 3)</sub>.

If you are writing code for production purposes, **don't do this**. It will break. I assume you are processing CSV. Stick with Perl, and `use Text::CSV`. Then:

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 });

open my $fh, "<:utf8", $ARGV[0];

my $keys = $csv->getline($fh);
my $vals = $csv->getline($fh);

my %hash;
@hash{@$keys} = @$vals;
```

It isn't even much longer, but very unlikely to break (It doesn't split on commas inside quotes).

Comment: Hi .. really appreciate your suggestion .. but I cant use perl as I'm working with mysql Database and don't have the DBI module (installation says a huge set of dependencies is needed)
So,the task at hand is to write a shell script that works with database and .csv .. thanks

Comment: So, I have a huge perl script .. that was just a snippet

Comment: @jakeryan Deciding that you can't install CPAN modules is unfortunate, but I'm sure you are operating under some unusual constraint that makes this impossible (although I can't imagine such a constraint). If you can't use Perl, you might want to learn some Python, it may be better suited than Bash. My point about here-docs was tongue-in-cheek. It is a common shell syntax where you can include the contents of a file in your script itself. It can then be passed to the STDIN of commands, e.g. the `perl` interpreter. My first code snippet shows this (where `...` is the original script).